# How to pip install compiled libraries like PyYAML without root access on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pyyaml

I am having a terribly difficult time getting the Python module PyYAML to install / compile.  I am working in a constrained linux environment (Ubuntu 14.04, I do **not** have root).  I don't think the issue is unique to PyYAML beyond the fact that it is the first library I've needed that requires `gcc` extensions to build.

I have managed to `apt-get` the following packages in a user folder because I cannot write to root owned folders but could try others if that makes more sense.

- python2.7-dev
- python3-dev

I've modified a few environment variables that have allowed me to get a partially operational python environment.  The `apt-get` target install is `${DEPS_DIR}/apt`:

```
export PYTHONHOME="${DEPS_DIR}/apt/usr"
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
export CPATH="${DEPS_DIR}/apt/usr/include/python2.7:${DEPS_DIR}/apt/usr/include"
export PATH="${DEPS_DIR}/apt/usr/local/bin"
```

I suspect I'm missing one or more variables or have paths in the wrong order to make this work properly.  Most searches on SO for the issue I'm seeing take for granted you can just `sudo` install.

This is the specific error I'm seeing when trying to `pip install PyYAML`:

> In file included from ext/_yaml.h:2:0,
>                    from ext/_yaml.c:271: /usr/include/yaml.h:633:1: note: expected ‘yaml_char_t *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’ 
>   yaml_mapping_start_event_initialize(yaml_event_t *event,  ^
>   x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
>   Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if
>   appropriate. See  for
>   instructions. error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit
>   status 4

I am using `pip -V` 9.0.1 and `python -V` is 2.7.6.  I tried to get virtualenv and wrapper installed at one point but didn't seem to really get it working like I can on my laptop.

Comment: If you were installing compiled libraries (i.e. wheels) then you don't need to compile them yourself. Have a look at [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/0.15.35) (disclaimer: I am the author), which is essentially a superset of PyYAML with many PyYAML bugs fixed. It has [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) created wheels for Linux, that are compiled libraries that install without need for a compiler and/or pythonX-dev packages.

Comment: I was a little surprised the wheel install failed.  I guess there is an `apt-get python-yaml` that helps get around this particular issue, but the above holds true for the next dependency `websocket-client` so I was suspicious of a general misconfiguration I need to address.

Comment: As an aside, I had looked at ruamel previously on another project specifically because it addressed the deletion of comments with PyYaml, so thanks for your efforts on that library!

Comment: If you install with `apt-get` you get precompiled binaries. If you do use `pip` you only get those if the linux wheels are available. For PyYAML these are not available, only the windows binaries are there (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some of the more troublesome python dependencies, there are oftentimes additional packages that can be installed locally to avoid some of the extension compilation issues.

The two libraries both have system packages that avoid needing to compile:

```
apt-get python-yaml
apt-get python-websocket
```